# I wasn't able to access remote server using SSH!

Tags: server, remote, 18.10

I wasn't able to access to remote server using ssh! What should I do?
I have installed firewall in my machine,now I uninstall it but it's still didn't connect!(the keypair is in the same directory.)
please help me!
[image]

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: Is ssh server installed on the remote computer? Do the firewall allow ssh trough? From what you post the traffic does not get trough at all - connection times out. That indicates that either sshd is not installed/running on the remote machine, or some firewall blocks it.

Comment: If this issue still actual, please launch your ssh command in verbose mode( just add key `-v` ) and show output.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `ubuntu` as your login, instead `ec2-user`.

Comment: The problem is not that the user is invalid. It says quite clearly that connection timed out. Connection time out happens in the TCP handshake stage; well before any username is transmitted.